# while installing ffmpeg giving error during make

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to install ffmpeg on ubuntu. and following this article http://pasindudps.blogspot.com/2010/12/compiling-ffmpeg-in-ubuntu-1010.html
but when m doing make after config

```
Then go to the ffmpeg folder.
cd ffmpeg
Start the installation
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc \
--enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb \
--enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis \
--enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab
make
```

giving this error

```
/home/reach121/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/cabac.h:93: undefined reference to `ff_h264_norm_shift'
/home/reach121/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/cabac.h:93: undefined reference to `ff_h264_lps_range'
/home/reach121/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/cabac.h:93: undefined reference to `ff_h264_norm_shift'
/home/reach121/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/cabac.h:93: undefined reference to `ff_h264_mlps_state'
/home/reach121/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/cabac.h:93: undefined reference to `ff_h264_norm_shift'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 1
```

Please suggest why this error is coming and what to do to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

For licensing reasons, FFmpeg does not include all codec libraries. You have to download, compile and install them separately. This is the case for MP3 and H.264 codecs.

A great guide that deals with this can be found here:

[Compilation Guide Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)

Comment: sorry i didnt able to get you , please suggest what i need to do

Comment: You have to install libx264. Some indications can be found at http://www.saiweb.co.uk/linux/ffmpeg-install-with-libx264-h264